# Read Excel file containing multiple values in single column -Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm reading Excel file using Apache POI.
My Excel table structure is like this

```
|2000s| 2001, 2003, 2008, 2009|
```

so for right hand side data, I require it to assign to 2000s

Till now I've implemented this way:

```
List<Class> list = new ArrayList<Class>();
        File file = new File(file_path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        //Create an instance of workbook which refers to an excel file
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        //This selects the 1st sheet 
        XSSFSheet sheet =  wb.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each row one by one
        Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
        String newName = null; 
        String oldName = null;


        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Row nextRow = itr.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                newName =  nextRow.getCell(0).toString();

                if(nextRow.getCell(1).toString().contains(",")){
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nextRow.getCell(1).toString(),",");
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                        oldName = st.nextToken();
                    }
                }
                else{
                     oldName = nextRow.getCell(1).toString();
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
```

When I compile, it throws me "Null pointer Exception" at `nextRow.getCell(1)` line.

I don't understand how do I map all comma values to  2000s.

This is working perfectly fine for normal data(without comma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma values have been handled

I'm posting answer so somebody can get help from here.

What I've done is- added String Tokenizer class and if there's comma in the cell, it breaks the value with the comma delimiter.

Lets have a look at the code below

```
 while(itr.hasNext()){
            Row nextRow = itr.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
               Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                newName =  nextRow.getCell(0).toString();

                if(nextRow.getCell(1).toString().contains(",")){
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nextRow.getCell(1).toString(),",");
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                        oldName = st.nextToken();
                    }
               }
                else{
                     oldName = nextRow.getCell(1).toString();
                    }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Here *newName* gets the value of 1st col.(2000s)
and *oldName* gets the tokens based on ',' delimiter- In this case 2001, 2003, 2008, 2009

for all these values of *oldName*, *newName* 2000s would be mapped.

**UPDATE**: Reason I was getting **'Null Pointer Exception'** there, because some cells at 2nd column(nextRow.getCell(1)) are null.

So whenever iterator reaches to the null cell, it throws Null Pointer Exception.
Here you need to assign **Missing Cell Policy**

by

```
Cell cell2 = row.getCell(j,org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

(It just treats null values as blank)

This way you can also *resolve Null pointer exception in Excel* while reading from Null values